# Hiding/Showing ListItem components vs Different listitem view

Tags: android, listview

My question is about listviews. Let's say for my listview I will have 3 types of different items,

1- list item with no image
2- list item with cover image
3- list item with 2x squared images in place of cover image

Lets say I can struct a list item like this

```
<LinearLayout>
   <ImageView visibility gone /><ImageView with visibility gone/>
</LinearLayout>
```

So, when I am writing my adapter for this listview, is it more convenient to use different layouts for these or use something like above and hide / show imageviews depending on image count. Is there any "better" ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would overwrite `getViewTypeCount()` and `getItemViewType(int position)`, and based on it in my `getView()` I'll hide/show the ImageViews. Your 3 types of items are not significantly different and the end result can be easily achieved with hiding/showing. Also as you'll be using the `getItemViewType(int position)`, Android will still be reusing lots of the views within your list.

Answer (score 0):

I solved that case in this way. Hope helpful for you.
Firstly, you have to create models for different types. And you should create custom layout for different models.
For example, I have two type: OneObject and TwoObject

```
public class MainObject { String type;
    public MainObject(String t){ this.type = t;}
}

public class OneObject extends MainObject { String image;
    public OneObject(String t, String image){
        super(t);
        this.image = image;
    }
}

public class TwoObject extends MainObject { String place;
        public TwoObject(String t, String p) {
        super(t);
        this.place = p;
    }
}
```

Then. When u add data to arraylist, you can add like this.

```
ArrayList<MainObject> objlist = new ArrayList<>();

        objlist.add(new MainObject("main"));
        objlist.add(new OneObject("one", "image"));
        objlist.add(new TwoObject("two","place"));
```

In adapter, you will get that ArrayList.And then you can check which model you should cast and which layout you should use. For example...

```
  ArrayList<MainObject> objlist = new ArrayList<>();


  //IN ADAPTER

  ..............

            MainObject obj = objlist.get(position);

             //u can check in other way 

            //if(obj.type.equals("one"))
            if(obj instanceof OneObject){
                //this object is "OneObject"
            }
            //else if(obj.type.equals("two"))
            else if(obj instanceof TwoObject){
                //this object is "TwoObject"
            }
            //else if(obj.type.equals("main"))
            else if(obj instanceof MainObject){
                //this object is "MainObject"
            }
```